# Spring Boot Cache - to do some logic before evict an object

Tags: spring-boot, caching, spring-cache

I need to update one field(last query time of this object) of some object in the cache many times without updating it in the database, but before spring removes the object from the cache, I need to update it in the database. Is there a way to configure the cache manager so that it automatically updates the deleted cached object in the database before deleting an object from the cache?

I am using standard annotations such as @Cacheable @CachePut @CacheEvict

Answer (score 0):

This is a loaded question since 1) the answer partly depends on the configured *caching provider* in use by your *Spring [Boot]* application (e.g. Redis) and 2) *Spring's Cache Abstraction* is just that, an "abstraction" (not a "cache implementation"), and technically leaves complex concerns, like [Eviction and Expiration policies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-specific-config) to the underly *caching provider*, where the mileage can vary greatly between different *caching providers* in this case (i.e. Redis, Hazelcast, Apache Geode, etc).

Having said that, and as you already know, *Spring* does provide general support for basic Eviction functionality (essentially all entries or a single entry based on key), via the declarative, [`@CacheEvict` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CacheEvict.html) (declared on application service component methods; also see [ref docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations-evict)) in addition to [programmatical support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html#evict-java.lang.Object-) (or [alternatively](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html#evictIfPresent-java.lang.Object-)) of Eviction via the `Cache` interface directly.

The quick and dirty answer is, there is no direct support provided by *Spring* out-of-the-box since it is 1) an abstraction but also, 2) there are many ways to solve this problem.

However, you do have several options here:

1. You could implement a solution directly in your `@CacheEvict` annotated application service component (bean) method, something like:

```java
@Service
class MyCachingBasedApplicationService {

  // NOTE: Use constructor-based injection instead
  
  @Autowired
  private CacheManager cacheManager;

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "Users")
  public void evictUser(String userId) {
    Cache userCache = this.cacheManager.getCache("Users");
    User target = userCache.get(userId, User.class);
    this.userRepository.save(target);
  }
```

Take note of the [beforeInvocation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CacheEvict.html#beforeInvocation--) attribute on the `@CacheEviction` annotation and decide what is the best configuration for your application in this instance.

Of course, this solution requires direct invocation of the application service component's `evictUser(..)` method shown above, and does not take into account the "natural" Eviction/Expiration policies that may also be intrinsic to the *caching provider*, as configured.

Additionally, (based on your situation, IIUC) there would be a window of time where the backing database and your cache is out-of-sync, and if consistency is a concern, then this most certainly could be a problem since you are not updating the cache object, like a `User`, until it is (explicitly) evicted from the cache, assuming, of course, more than a `lastAccessedTime` field/property is also being updated in this case, or the `lastAccessedTime` field/property is essential to the correct behavior of your application as seen from the database (directly), possibly by other parts of your application, or from other applications sharing the same data through the database.

2. Alternatively, when the cache object is accessed from the cache and subsequently updated, such as updating a `lastAccessedTime` field/property of a `User`, then once the mutating application service operation is complete, the cache object could be updated along with the corresponding database record in realtime, by calling a `@CachePut` annotated application service component method. In this way `@CacheEvict` annotated application service component methods would not need to concern themselves with updating the database during only eviction, as suggested/implied in #1 above. Arguably, in addition to the general use of caching, that is, fast access and minimizing latency between the application and external application resources (database(s), message queue(s), other Microservices, etc), caching can also be used to keep a consistent view of frequently accessed data, to the extent possible.

However, this approach is likely to lead to more database traffic every time the cache object is accessed/updated and "put" back into the cache.

3. Often times these concerns are best left to the underlying *caching provider*.

For instance, (DISCLAIMER: my area of expertise resides with Apache Geode) when using [Apache Geode as a *caching provider* in Spring's Cache Abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#geode-caching-provider), an Apache Geode [`Region`](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/Region.html) is the backing store for a "named" `Cache` [instance](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/cache/GemfireCache.html) returned by Spring's `CacheManager` [implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/cache/GemfireCacheManager.html) provided by *Spring Data for Apache Geode* (SDG).

An Apache Geode `Region` allows the [registration](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/RegionFactory.html#addCacheListener-org.apache.geode.cache.CacheListener-) of a [`CacheListener`](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/CacheListener.html). The `CacheListener` interface allows the eviction ([invalidation](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/CacheListener.html#afterInvalidate-org.apache.geode.cache.EntryEvent-) or [destruction](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/CacheListener.html#afterDestroy-org.apache.geode.cache.EntryEvent-)) of the cache entry to be handled in the caching tier, or by the *caching provider* directly.

The benefit here is that this approach is usually more efficient and can scale more gracefully long with handling other concerns, like consistency, especially in a client/server and/or distributed caching solution.

The downside, of course, is that the solution/implementation is clearly *caching provider* specific, and will need to be changed if you ever change *caching providers* (e.g. from Geode to Redis, Redis to Hazelcast, and so on and so forth).

There are many other concerns that I did not allude to in my answer you should be aware of.

There are also other solutions you might be able to think of, like using a custom Spring AOP aspect (Spring's Cache Abstraction is AOP based after all and it essentially boils down to ordering AOP Aspects appropriately), implementing more sophisticated extensions to *Spring's Cache Abstraction* (and specifically, the primary `Cache` and `CacheManager` interfaces at the heart of the abstraction), etc.

At any rate, I hope this gives you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you a specific implementation since your question is vague. However, I can think of a general approach to your problem.

Assumptions: you can identify your database record by the cache key alone. This is important because the `evict` operation is only associated with the key, not the value.

To do what you want:

1. you can declare a cache "decorator". one such example is: `TransactionAwareCacheDecorator`
2. your cache provider's `CacheManager` probably extends `AbstractCacheManager`, which provides an interface method: `decorateCache`. If it does not, see below.
3. you can extend your cache provider's `CacheManager` and override `decorateCache` to decorate the native cache object.
4. in your cache decorator implementation, you do what you need before or after the native eviction.
5. If your cache provider's `CacheManager` does not extend `AbstractCacheManager`, too bad. It's a lot more trouble. You'll have to look into the provider's implementation to see if you can somehow intercept `Cache` object creation to insert your decoration.

Hope this helps.